# Why do moderators block people on this forum because they have different opinions on religion?

Tags: discussion

Blocking people because they have different opinions is just ridiculous ...

Is this the dogma of your belief system?

Fairly disappointed, I would have expected more from religious folks.

Comment: Don't just express your opinions. Bring out your best skeptical questions and post them. Problem solved.

Comment: As suggested, this question is more appropriate for the meta-site.
But if you want a serious answer to it, please include explicit examples of "*Blockin people because they have different opinions*".

Comment: I might answer this but I doubt you want to hear from me for the 4th time today. This website is not a forum, it is a Q&A website. It's not a Christian website either, it's a secular website about Christianity.

Answer (score 4):

First, it isn't people that are blocked, it is inappropriate (for *this* site) questions and answers that are downvoted, closed, or deleted.

"Different opinions" is seldom the reason for this.

I have up-voted answers that I disagree with, because they were well written and well explained.

I have down-voted or voted to close answers that I *do* agree with, because they were poorly written or inappropriate for this site.

Questions are supposed to be objectively asked, and asked about specific Christian doctrines or denominations.

An ideal answer should look like an article in an encyclopedia, written by an atheist that is interested in religion.
It should be totally objective, logical, and factual, without any explicit opinions.
Words like "I", "me", "my", etc. will almost never appear in it.

Really bad questions and answers tend to begin with "I believe", and are highly subjective and opinionated.

You haven't given an explicit example of the problem you noticed, but I'm fairly sure it will be of the latter form.

Comment: Thank you, this was my first time and last time posting on a religious forum or religious Q&A site or whatever you call it. Believe what ever made up deity you want. Have a pleasant evening.

Comment: Good answer, but I need to make one personal distinction on the "I believe" part, if you're like most of us and don't have any particular faculty to each on the matter of Christianity and you subscribe to a faith tradition that has a rather rigorous teaching authority behind it, "I believe" as in "I think" is as good as it gets - any more is presumption. So it _can_ be a bad answer smell, but not necessarily.

Comment: @PeterTurner, Agreed.  I didn't mean "*I believe that the LDS Church teaches that …*" (a fact that I can't 100% guarantee); I meant "*I believe that Jesus was trying to …*" (my personal opinion about something).

Comment: @RayButterworth says: An ideal answer should look like an article in an encyclopedia, written by an atheist that is interested in religion. It should be totally objective, . . . Even atheists have prejudices.  Your point is that contributors strive to take the evidence in the biblical text or in church documents in order to knit together a coherent (persuasive?) response to the question being posed.  To do this effectively, its better not to focus on yourself.   Rather, write it as as an impersonal encyclopedia article.  Let the light of your logical use of sources prevail.  Cool your passion.

Answer (score -3):

You can't change such bias from the administration here. You have to avoid posting things that go against mainstream religion of Christians. For secular or open minded biblical interpretation, see hermeneutics.stackexchange.

Comment: Unfortunately, BH-SE is almost as poorly structured with its inherent biases too. Poor exegesis is rewarded and sound Biblical content is dismissed. The Creeds are more important and it shows consistently. +1 for effort!

Comment: We cannot help with the popular choice for upvotes, it's not necessarily gonna coincide with the best accurate answers, but BHSE is far better when it comes to open mindedness, openness to divergent ideas or doctrines.